# Excel data file for menu program

Tags: c, excel, menu, pic

I have written a menu program in C for a PIC24 microcontroller, using the Microchip MPLAB X IDE. The menus are constructed from a data file at runtime. The data file is currently an Assembler file which is linked with the C program file, but it is difficult to maintain. What I would like to do is build the data file in an Excel spreadsheet then export it in some way (.csv ?) and add it to the menu project, but don’t know how to go about this. Bearing in mind that the data file contains variable and function identifiers contained in the program.

Comment: Vague, incomplete, overly broad. Voting for close, sorry.

Comment: If you give us something a bit more concrete we might be able to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question as it stands is quite vague, but here goes.

Your assembler/C code needs the data in a given format, to be able to assemble/compile.

You suggest using Excel to maintain the menus... your assembler/compiler will not understand xls or csv (or most likely xml) so a direct export is not an option.

However, you could write a VBA script to generate an asm/c file from the Excel data.